Nginx subdomain configuration, Failed to load API definition
I'm having trouble configuring nginx for subdomains.
My goal is eventually to have:
- example.com
- swagger.example.com
- api.example.com

I'm currently having problems with swagger.example.com.
My backend is written in FastAPI and I want swagger from localhost:8000/docs to be available on that domain.
But all I get is Failed to load API definition.
Somehow api.example.com/docs is working perfectly fine, though I haven't configured it in nginx yet.
user nginx;
worker_processes 4;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name .example.com;

        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name triptip.pro;
        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://example_service:8000;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name swagger.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://example_service:8000/docs;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }
}

What am I missing?

I've made a temporal solution, which redirects to working swagger when I request swagger.example.com
    server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name swagger.example.pro;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.pro/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.pro/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    
    location = / {
        return 301 https://$host/docs;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://example_service:8000;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

But if I try to block other endpoints with return 404, or change "location /"
in some way, swagger error reappears because of missing openapi.json.
@MatsLindh gave me a correct hint about source of a problem, but I don't want to change internal link here.

The swagger endpoint expects to load the openapi specification from /openapi.json - since you've mounted the sub path directly on /, there is no openapi.json present at root any longer.
You can change where FastAPI exposes the openapi specification by giving the openapi_url parameter when creating the FastAPI instance:
FastAPI(openapi_url="/docs/openapi.json")

However, this means that the /docs endpoint might try to load it from /docs under the docs itself, so you might have to define the url to use manually.
